# How to pass an array to asmx web service via JSON?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, web-services

I want to pass array value to my web service file. But it throws the following error

> setDeleteFiles
>
> Test
>
> The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters.

Here is my jquery code

```
$('#btnDeleteFiles').click(function () {
    var filesPaths = [];
    i = 0;
    $("input:checkbox[name=filed-checkedbox]:checked").each(function () {
        filesPaths[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
    });

    //alert("filesPaths  =  " + filesPaths)
    var location = $('#ddlLocation option:selected').text();
    alert("Location = "+location)
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "GetAllFolderDetails.asmx/setDeleteFiles",
        data: {
            location: location,
            fileNames: filesPaths
        },

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.reload(true);
            //alert("Success");

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

**GetAllFolderDetails.asmx** code

```
[WebMethod]
public void setDeleteFiles(string location, string[] fileNames)
{
    var locationID = 0;
    var domain = "domain";
    var username = "xxx";   //username
    var Password = "***";    //password

    Debug.WriteLine("Location = "+location);
    Debug.WriteLine("fileNames = " + fileNames);

    using (new ImpersonateUser(username , domain, Password))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Files names = "+ fileNames);
        foreach (string file in fileNames)
        {
            FileInfo files = new FileInfo(file);
            files.Delete();
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize("Files are successfully Deleted"));
    }
}
```

**Note**

> If I pass a `string` as a parameter without an array, it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
data: JSON.stringify({ location: location, fileNames: filesPaths }),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

and change the input parameter datatype as `List<string>` instead of `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
 dataType: "json",
```

from your ajax call.
and also check in your asmx file that it is decorated with

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

try this.